# make Colors.xml dynamic by referecing to theme

Tags: android, layout, resources, android-styles

How can I have colros defined in **Colors.xml** as dynamic?

My static colors.xml is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="background">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="foreground">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

By I need something like this which refers to colors defined in **themes.xml**.
The way I defined colors in below **doesn't work**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="background">?theme_color_background</color>
    <color name="foreground">?theme_color_foreground</color>
</resources>
```

I need this way to keep an old big project intact and just change theme.
I referenced colors.xml like this in old project in a way like this:

```
<TextView textColor="@colors/foreground"/>
```

Comment: why not just call it directly from the textColor instead of wrapping it in color.xml

Comment: As i said its for old project and referenced colors.xml hundreds of time in different layouts

Comment: post your them_color

Comment: You could what@  @Rod_Algonquin suggested and then do a global replace on `textColor="@colors/foreground"`

Answer (score 1):

You can not reference a color from your `theme` but you can reference a color from the android default `color.xml` to wrap it in your `color.xml`

**sample:**

```
<color name="black">@android:color/background_dark</color>
```